# Add an imagestyle to a template twig

Tags: 8, media

Im using the [Aegan](https://www.drupal.org/project/aegan) theme, and it uses it's own slideshow. Now I'd like it to use a specific image style, that formats the images according to my presets.

The code in the page.html.twig looks like this

```
{# Include a slider. #}
  {% if slider %}
    <div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        {% for slide in slider %}
          <li>
            <a href="{{ slide.url }}"><img src="{{ slide.src }}" alt="{{ slide.name }}"></a>
            {% if slide.description %}
              <p class="flex-caption">{{ slide.description | raw }}</p>
            {% endif %}
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>{% endif %}
```

The style is called aegan_slide (don't really know where I can find it. But how do I apply my custom style to this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use sub themes of Aegan, you need edit file **aegan.theme**

Add more use class at top:

```
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;
```

Replace code line 53->73

```
if ($slideshow_path && $show_slideshow) {
    $vars['slider'] = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= theme_get_setting('slideshow_count', 'aegan'); $i++) {
      $fid = theme_get_setting("slide_image_{$i}", "aegan");
      if (!empty($fid)) {
        $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid[0]);
        $uri = $file->getFileUri();
        $image_path = file_create_url($uri);
      }
      else {
        $image_path = THEME_PATH . "/images/slide-{$i}.jpg";
      }
      $vars['slider'][] = array(
        'name' => !empty($fid) ? $file->getFilename() : "slider-{$i}",
        'url' => theme_get_setting("slide_url_{$i}", "aegan"),
        'src' => $image_path,
        'description' => theme_get_setting("slide_description_{$i}", "aegan"),
      );
    }
  }
```

with

```
if ($slideshow_path && $show_slideshow) {
    $vars['slider'] = array();
    //replace large with image style you want
    $image_style = 'large';
    $image = ImageStyle::load($image_style);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= theme_get_setting('slideshow_count', 'aegan'); $i++) {
      $fid = theme_get_setting("slide_image_{$i}", "aegan");
      if (!empty($fid)) {
        $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid[0]);
        $uri = $file->getFileUri();
        $image_path = $image->buildUrl($uri);
      }
      else {
        $image_path = THEME_PATH . "/images/slide-{$i}.jpg";
      }
      $vars['slider'][] = array(
        'name' => !empty($fid) ? $file->getFilename() : "slider-{$i}",
        'url' => theme_get_setting("slide_url_{$i}", "aegan"),
        'src' => $image_path,
        'description' => theme_get_setting("slide_description_{$i}", "aegan"),
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Trying this out right now, sorry for late answer, but I think it's working. Thanx very much for your help.